# Does anybody have "New Task" implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler sample code?

Tags: apex, action

Anybody has sample code for "New Task" action implementing QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler on Case Feed layout?

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 1):

```
global class EmailPublisherLoader implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
// Empty constructor
global EmailPublisherLoader() {
}

// The main interface method
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
    QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null;


    // Check if the quick action is the standard Case Feed send email action
    for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {
        if (defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults && 
           defaults.get(j).getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == 
               EmailMessage.sObjectType && 
           defaults.get(j).getActionName().equals('Case.Email') && 
           defaults.get(j).getActionType().equals('Email')) {
               sendEmailDefaults = 
                   (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
               break;
        }
    }

    if (sendEmailDefaults != null) {
        Case c = [SELECT Status, Reason FROM Case 
                  WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];

        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();    
        // Set bcc address to make sure each email goes for audit
        emailMessage.BccAddress = getBccAddress(c.Reason);

        /* 
        Set Template related fields 
        When the In Reply To Id field is null we know the interface 
        is called on page load. Here we check if 
        there are any previous emails attached to the case and load 
        the 'New_Case_Created' or 'Automatic_Response' template.
        When the In Reply To Id field is not null we know that 
        the interface is called on click of reply/reply all 
        of an email and we load the 'Default_reply_template' template
        */
        if (sendEmailDefaults.getInReplyToId() == null) {
            Integer emailCount = [SELECT count() FROM EmailMessage 
                                  WHERE ParentId=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
            if (emailCount!= null && emailCount > 0) {
                sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                    getTemplateIdHelper('Automatic_Response'));
            } else {
                sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                    getTemplateIdHelper('New_Case_Created'));
            }
            sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(false);
            sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);
        } else {
            sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                getTemplateIdHelper('Default_reply_template'));
            sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(false);
            sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(true);
        }
    }
}

private Id getTemplateIdHelper(String templateApiName) {
    Id templateId = null;
    try {
        templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate 
                      where developername = : templateApiName].id;   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('Unble to locate EmailTemplate using name: ' + 
            templateApiName + ' refer to Setup | Communications Templates ' 
                + templateApiName);
    }
    return templateId;
 }

}
```

Shamelessly copied from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm) .Reproducing so it does help others googling

Comment: Hari ...I don't think this interface supports task ..it only supports email